# Angular/typescript Sort larger than 0 sort smaller than 0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey so I got this problem.

I want to make an input field that will sort numbers larger than selected value &

I want to make an input field that sorts the numbers smaller than selected value. Is this possible to do?

Note: I already have a button that will sort the orders in asc - desc order. Now I want to filter out the onces that are larger or smaller than

Here's a plunker/stackblitz of the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pypfy4

Comment: Take a look at [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), not sort.

Comment: Try using `filter` for your array. For example, `this.arr= this.arr.filter((val)=>{return (val > smallValue) && (val < largeValue)})`

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind your input values to parameters:

```
export class AppComponent  {
    name = 'Angular';

    larger: number;  // parameter for binding 
    smaller:number;  // parameter for binding 

    isAscendic = true
```

and connect it via `ngModel` in `HTML`

```
<input type="number" name="larger" [(ngModel)]="larger" placeholder="Input > than">
<input type="number" name="smaller" [(ngModel)]="smaller" placeholder="Input < than">
```

now you just need a filter `this.fruits`

```
if(this.larger)
    this.fruits = this.fruits.filter(i=>i > this.larger);

if(this.smaller)
    this.fruits = this.fruits.filter(i=>i < this.smaller);
```

Comment: Would this be added in to a pipe file? Or can I just write this in the app.component.ts file? Also thanks :)!

Comment: it's just a sample - you can organize it whatever you want